# How to send/convert curl request to Http request Apex

Tags: apex

To upload bank statements, send the Authorization Header as above and send the pk of a book you previously created and the file you want to upload as a "**HTML multipart form (not a JSON)**" to

**cURL:**

$ curl -X POST \ 
    -H "Authorization: Basic dGVzdDZAb2Nyb2x1cy5jb206dGVzdGluZw==" \
    -F 'pk=10399' \
    -F 'upload=@../bank-statement.pdf' \

**Apex Http Request:**

```
public static String uploadFile(String method,Blob file_body, String file_name, String resourceName,Integer bookId){

    String response ='';
    try{
        String boundary = '----------------------------741e90d31eff';
        String header = '--'+boundary+'\nContent-Disposition: form-data; pk="'+bookId+'"; upload="'+file_name+'";\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data';//application/octet-stream

        System.debug('header>>> '+header);

        String footer = '--'+boundary+'--';             
        String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
        while(headerEncoded.endsWith('=')){
            header+=' ';
            headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
        }


        String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file_body);


        Blob bodyBlob = null;
        String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length()-4,bodyEncoded.length());


        if(last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {

            last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,2) + '0K';
            bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
            // We have appended the \r\n to the Blob, so leave footer as it is.
            String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
            bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
        } else if(last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {

            last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,3) + 'N';
            bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
            // We have appended the CR e.g. \r, still need to prepend the line feed to the footer
            footer = '\n' + footer;
            String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
            bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);              
        } else {
            // Prepend the CR LF to the footer
            footer = '\r\n' + footer;
            String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
            bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);  
        }

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        String userName = ocrolusSettings.lendingxl__UserName__c;
        String password = ocrolusSettings.lendingxl__Password__c;
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(userName+ ':' +password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' +EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        System.debug('authorizationHeader>>>'+authorizationHeader);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

        req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setEndpoint(ocrolusSettings.lendingxl__EndPoint__c+ resourceName);//
        //req.setEndpoint(reqEndPoint);
        req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
        req.setBody('{"pk" : "'+bookId+'"}');
        req.setTimeout(120000);

        Http http = new Http();

        System.debug('req>>> '+req);
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        response =res.getBody();
        System.debug('response>>> '+response);
        //return res.getBody();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Error Message >>> '+e.getMessage());
        System.debug('Error Message >>> '+e.getStackTraceString());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Above code is what I have tried but not able to upload the file.

Response what I receive when Http request is made

{"status": 400, "message": "required key not provided @ data['pk']", "code": 1003, "meta": {"status": 400, "msg": "required key not provided @ data['pk']", "code": 1003}, "response": null}

Comment: So, what kind of issue do you have with that?

Comment: Want the Http request for above curl request.

Comment: I can recommend you to debug your requests from curl and apex using url from https://requestb.in/ to see what are you actually sending from curl and apex, and perform necessary adjustments

Answer (score 1):

on multipart requests the body contains the whole data including the blob separated by the boundary you specified in the request header. You can find the specification [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867#section-6).

If you don't wan't to struggle around implementing default protocol specification just use [ffhttp-core](https://github.com/financialforcedev/ffhttp-core)